# I want to kill a process but zygote relaunches it

Tags: android, kill, ps, lsof, dumpsys

I use android and I know the process I want to kill but everytime I kill it the zygote launches it back I don't know what deamon is monitoring the process neither which calls the zygote socket, please help me, internet!

ps faux is not showing anything

it is not an important process it is a process that listen to a port and when it is killed the system keeps on working normally

here is the complete (i guess) list of services running normally on the phone

```
adb shell service list
Found 168 services:
0   IextSDUFsService.unionFSStackService: []      acho ok
1   ims6: [com.sec.ims.IImsService]
2   secims: [com.samsung.commonimsinterface.imscommon.internal.IVolteService]
3   sip: [android.net.sip.ISipService]
4   volte: [com.sec.ims.volte2.IVolteService]
5   SveService: []
6   telecom: [com.android.internal.telecom.ITelecomService]
7   carrier_config: [com.android.internal.telephony.ICarrierConfigLoader]
8   phone: [com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony]
9   emergency_service: []
10  isms: [com.android.internal.telephony.ISms]
11  iphonesubinfo: [com.android.internal.telephony.IPhoneSubInfo]
12  simphonebook: [com.android.internal.telephony.IIccPhoneBook]
13  isub: [com.android.internal.telephony.ISub]
14  sec_analytics: [com.sec.analytics.data.collection.serviceif.IDataCollectionManager]
15  edmnativehelper: [mdm.edmnativehelperservice]
16  gamemanager: [com.samsung.android.game.IGameManagerService]
17  imms: [com.android.internal.telephony.IMms]
18  lpnet: [android.os.ILpnetManager]
19  media_projection: [android.media.projection.IMediaProjectionManager]
20  voip: [android.os.IVoIPInterface]
21  launcherapps: [android.content.pm.ILauncherApps]
22  fingerprint: [android.hardware.fingerprint.IFingerprintService]
23  trust: [android.app.trust.ITrustManager]
24  media_router: [android.media.IMediaRouterService]
25  media_session: [android.media.session.ISessionManager]
26  restrictions: [android.content.IRestrictionsManager]
27  print: [android.print.IPrintManager]
28  graphicsstats: [android.view.IGraphicsStats]
29  dreams: [android.service.dreams.IDreamManager]
30  commontime_management: []
31  samplingprofiler: []
32  AAS: [com.samsung.android.allaroundsensing.IAASManager]
33  DisplaySolution: [com.samsung.android.displaysolution.IDisplaySolutionManager]
34  mDNIe: [com.samsung.android.mdnie.IMdnieManager]
35  com.samsung.ucs.ucsservice: [com.sec.enterprise.knox.ucm.core.IUcmService]
36  diskstats: []
37  voiceinteraction: [com.android.internal.app.IVoiceInteractionManagerService]
38  appwidget: [com.android.internal.appwidget.IAppWidgetService]
39  backup: [android.app.backup.IBackupManager]
40  jobscheduler: [android.app.job.IJobScheduler]
41  kiesusb: []
42  serial: [android.hardware.ISerialManager]
43  usb: [android.hardware.usb.IUsbManager]
44  midi: [android.media.midi.IMidiManager]
45  DockObserver: []
46  audio: [android.media.IAudioService]
47  wallpaper: [android.app.IWallpaperManager]
48  dropbox: [com.android.internal.os.IDropBoxManagerService]
49  search: [android.app.ISearchManager]
50  country_detector: [android.location.ICountryDetector]
51  location: [android.location.ILocationManager]
52  devicestoragemonitor: []
53  notification: [android.app.INotificationManager]
54  updatelock: [android.os.IUpdateLock]
55  servicediscovery: [android.net.nsd.INsdManager]
56  epdg: [com.sec.epdg.IEpdgManager]
57  connectivity: [android.net.IConnectivityManager]
58  ethernet: [android.net.IEthernetManager]
59  rttmanager: [android.net.wifi.IRttManager]
60  wifiscanner: [android.net.wifi.IWifiScanner]
61  wifihs20: [android.net.wifi.hs20.IWifiHs20Manager]
62  wifi: [android.net.wifi.IWifiManager]
63  wifip2p: [android.net.wifi.p2p.IWifiP2pManager]
64  netpolicy: [android.net.INetworkPolicyManager]
65  netstats: [android.net.INetworkStatsService]
66  network_score: [android.net.INetworkScoreService]
67  textservices: [com.android.internal.textservice.ITextServicesManager]
68  network_management: [android.os.INetworkManagementService]
69  clipboard: [android.content.IClipboard]
70  statusbar: [com.android.internal.statusbar.IStatusBarService]
71  enterprise_policy: [android.app.enterprise.IEnterpriseDeviceManager]
72  knox_ccm_policy: [com.sec.enterprise.knox.ccm.IClientCertificateManager]
73  knox_timakeystore_policy: [com.sec.enterprise.knox.keystore.ITimaKeystore]
74  enterprise_shared_device_policy: [com.sec.enterprise.knox.shareddevice.aidl.IEnterpriseSharedDevicePolicy]
75  enterprise_billing_policy: [com.sec.enterprise.knox.billing.IEnterpriseBillingPolicy]
76  mum_container_policy: [com.sec.enterprise.knox.container.IKnoxContainerManager]
77  edm_proxy: [android.sec.enterprise.IEDMProxy]
78  knox_ucsm_policy: [com.sec.enterprise.knox.ucm.configurator.IUniversalCredentialManager]
79  remoteinjection: [android.app.enterprise.remotecontrol.IRemoteInjection]
80  phone_restriction_policy: [android.app.enterprise.IPhoneRestrictionPolicy]
81  wifi_policy: [android.app.enterprise.IWifiPolicy]
82  application_policy: [android.app.enterprise.IApplicationPolicy]
83  enterprise_license_policy: [android.app.enterprise.license.IEnterpriseLicense]
84  log_manager_service: [android.app.enterprise.ILogManager]
85  dlp: [android.content.IDLPManager]
86  sdp_log: [com.sec.sdp.ISdpLogService]
87  sdp: [com.sec.sdp.ISdpManagerService]
88  harmony_eas_service: [android.content.IHarmonyEAS]
89  device_policy: [android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager]
90  deviceidle: [android.os.IDeviceIdleController]
91  persistent_data_block: [android.service.persistentdata.IPersistentDataBlockService]
92  lock_settings: [com.android.internal.widget.ILockSettings]
93  uimode: [android.app.IUiModeManager]
94  mount: [IMountService]
95  FMPlayer: [com.samsung.android.media.fmradio.internal.IFMPlayer]
96  motion_recognition: [com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService]
97  accessibility: [android.view.accessibility.IAccessibilityManager]
98  input_method: [com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodManager]
99  rcp: [android.os.IRCPManager]
100 bluetooth_secure_mode_manager: [android.bluetooth.IBluetoothSecureManagerService]
101 bluetooth_manager: [android.bluetooth.IBluetoothManager]
102 input: [android.hardware.input.IInputManager]
103 window: [android.view.IWindowManager]
104 CCM: [CCM]
105 alarm: [android.app.IAlarmManager]
106 consumer_ir: [android.hardware.IConsumerIrService]
107 CustomFrequencyManagerService: [android.os.ICustomFrequencyManager]
108 emailksproxy: [com.samsung.android.emailksproxy.IEmailKeystoreService]
109 cepproxyks: [com.samsung.android.cepproxyks.ISCEPKeystoreService]
110 iccc: [com.samsung.android.iccc.IIntegrityControlCheckCenter]
111 pkm: [android.service.tima.IPKMService]
112 tima: [android.service.tima.ITimaService]
113 vibrator: [android.os.IVibratorService]
114 sedenial: [android.service.ISEDenialService]
115 SatsService: [com.samsung.android.service.sats.ISatsService]
116 EngineeringModeService: [com.samsung.android.service.EngineeringMode.IEngineeringModeService]
117 DeviceRootKeyService: [com.samsung.android.service.DeviceRootKeyService.IDeviceRootKeyService]
118 VaultKeeperService: [com.samsung.android.service.vaultkeeper.IVaultKeeperService]
119 ReactiveService: [com.samsung.android.service.reactive.IReactiveService]
120 DirEncryptService: [IDirEncryptService]
121 content: [android.content.IContentService]
122 account: [android.accounts.IAccountManager]
123 media.camera.proxy: [android.hardware.ICameraServiceProxy]
124 SEAMService: [com.sec.enterprise.knox.seams.ISEAMS]
125 persona: [android.os.IPersonaManager]
126 telephony.registry: [com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephonyRegistry]
127 scheduling_policy: [android.os.ISchedulingPolicyService]
128 webviewupdate: [android.webkit.IWebViewUpdateService]
129 usagestats: [android.app.usage.IUsageStatsManager]
130 battery: []
131 mdm.remotedesktop: [mdm.samsung.IRemoteDesktopService]
132 sensorservice: [android.gui.SensorServer]
133 processinfo: [android.os.IProcessInfoService]
134 permission: [android.os.IPermissionController]
135 cpuinfo: []
136 dbinfo: []
137 gfxinfo: []
138 meminfo: []
139 procstats: [com.android.internal.app.IProcessStats]
140 activity: [android.app.IActivityManager]
141 user: [android.os.IUserManager]
142 package: [android.content.pm.IPackageManager]
143 persona_policy: [android.content.pm.IPersonaPolicyManager]
144 display: [android.hardware.display.IDisplayManager]
145 power: [android.os.IPowerManager]
146 appops: [com.android.internal.app.IAppOpsService]
147 batterystats: [com.android.internal.app.IBatteryStats]
148 media.mmsdk: [com.mediatek.mmsdk.IMMSdkService]
149 media.mediacapture: [android.media.IMediaCaptureService]
150 media.radio: [android.hardware.IRadioService]
151 media.sound_trigger_hw: [android.hardware.ISoundTriggerHwService]
152 media.audio_policy: [android.media.IAudioPolicyService]
153 media.camera: [android.hardware.ICameraService]
154 memory_dumper: [android.memory.IMemoryDumper]
155 media.resource_manager: [android.media.IResourceManagerService]
156 media.player: [android.media.IMediaPlayerService]
157 media.audio_flinger: [android.media.IAudioFlinger]
158 drm.drmManager: [drm.IDrmManagerService]
159 android.security.keystore: [android.security.IKeystoreService]
160 android.service.gatekeeper.IGateKeeperService: []
161 GuiExtService: [GuiExtService]
162 NvRAMAgent: []
163 DmAgent: []
164 IextSDUFsServiceVold.unionFSStackServiceVold: []
165 batteryproperties: [android.os.IBatteryPropertiesRegistrar]
166 SurfaceFlinger: [android.ui.ISurfaceComposer]
167 PQ: []
```

Comment: are you running service?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: are you developing app which uses that service?

Comment: nope, just a regular user trying to find the deamon responsible for calling back the process i'm trying to kill